# Conditional formatting in React - adding or appending CSS classes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

What's a more concise way to apply conditional formatting to this statement?

```
const PaginationStorePageLink = ({ store, pageNum }) => (observer(({ PaginationStore }) => {
  if (this.props.store.currentPage === this.props.pageNum) {
    return (
      <PaginationLink className={styles.bold} onClick={this.props.store.goToPage(this.props.pageNum)} />
    );
  }
  return (
    <PaginationLink className={styles.primary} onClick={this.props.store.goToPage(this.props.pageNum)} />
  );
}));
```

Specifically, if the current page number is detected as being current, the ".bold" class should be applied. Otherwise, the ".primary" class should be applied.

As a related question, is it possible to append classes to each other? So for example, the ".primary" class is applied either way, but ".bold .primary" is applied if the conditions are met?

Comment: For the 2nd Q, check out [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) which is very handy library for manipulating classes. (About 370B though - https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=classnames@2.2.6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const PaginationStorePageLink = ({ store, pageNum }) => (observer(({ PaginationStore }) => {
  const style = store.currentPage === pageNum ? styles.bold : styles.primary;

  return (
    <PaginationLink className={style} onClick={store.goToPage(pageNum)} />
  );
}));
```

For the second question, you could apply both classes (`".bold .primary"`) if you want styles from both CSS classes to be applied.

Comment: could also use an object to map styles to conditions. if there is a necessity for more then 2-3 styles id recommend going that approach so you don't get into ternary hell :) got my vote regardless! :)

Comment: Could you explain how it works, logically? Specifically, this line: `this.props.pageNum ? styles.bold : styles.primary;` - I see what you're doing, but want to make sure I understand why it works. :)

Comment: That's a ternary expression, it's equivalent to `let style = styles.primary; if(this.props.store.currentPage === this.props.pageNum) style = styles.bold;`. Basically picking out the right style to use with a conditional like you were doing in your original code, but storing it in a variable to avoid duplication.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: So if I were modifying it to have both expressions by default:

  `const style = this.props.store.currentPage === this.props.pageNumber ? styles.primary.bold : styles.primary;` 

That would make `styles.primary.bold` the one activated by the conditional, and `styles.primary` would be the default?

Comment: Basically yes, you can read that as: if condition `? (then)` value `: (else)` defaultValue